# Hook-length formula (equivalent)

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, young-tableaux

I would like to know if anyone knows where I can find a proof
for the equivalent hook-length formula

$$f^{\lambda}=\frac{n! \cdot \prod_{i<j}(l_i-l_j)}{l_1! \cdot l_2! \cdot ... \cdot l_k!}$$

where if $\lambda=(\lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2\geq ...\geq \lambda_k \geq 0)$ is a partition, then $l_i=\lambda_i-i + k$ for all $i$.

I have seen the formula in the book Young Tableaux of William Fulton.

Comment: *A Course in Combinatorics* by Van Lint and Wilson.

Comment: (5.17.1) in [Pavel Etingof, Oleg Golberg, Sebastian Hensel, Tiankai Liu, Alex Schwendner, Dmitry Vaintrob, and Elena Yudovina, *Introduction to representation theory*](http://www-math.mit.edu/~etingof/reprbook.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*A Course in Combinatorics* by Van Lint and Wilson has a proof (Theorem 15.10).

*Enumerative Combinatorics Vol. 2* by Richard Stanley has a proof (see Lemma 7.21.1, equation 7.101)

*A Course in Enumeration* by Martin Aigner has a proof (around page 388)

*Symmetric Functions and Hall Polynomials* by Ian Macdonald I believe has a proof, but I can't check right now.

(5.17.1) in [*Introduction to Representation Theory*](http://www-math.mit.edu/~etingof/reprbook.pdf) by Pavel Etingof, Oleg Golberg, Sebastian Hensel, Tiankai Liu, Alex Schwendner, Dmitry Vaintrob, and Elena Yudovina with historical interludes by Slava Gerovitch